# SWIFT5: Initilize only selected variables in init method

Tags: swift5

Is there a way to use init method without initializing Binding parameters? If they are not mentioned, I get error of "Initialize all parameters". If they are initialized, then it gives another error.

How can I avoid initialising them?

```
    struct DetailView: View {
        
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        @Binding var quest: QuestObject
                    
        @State var selectedOption : String = ""
        
        init()
        {
            //self.isPresented = $isPresented //I would like to skip initializing this paremeter
            //self.quest = $quest             //I would like to skip initializing this paremeter
    
            self.selectedOption = "Apples"
            
        }
```